# Send SD data connected to Arduino to a Webhost using FTP

Tags: arduino, sd, host

Sorry, I'm not very expert in drawing schematics, so this is the best I can do!

I want to connect my arduino to GSM/GPS Shield offered by Cookinghacks.com

http://www.cooking-hacks.com/3g-gprs-shield-for-arduino-3g-gps-audio-video-kit

Now, the device will be kept inside the car as a data logger. I want the device to store the location of the car, and it should also take a picture while will be saved as well on the SD card.

Now I want the system to be able every let's say 5 hours, to upload the picture and the text file containning the GPS location to an online host I've created using 3G.

How could I upload images-text files to a webserver using FTP?

Comment: The answer to "is there any way" is "yes".  Perhaps edit the question to highlight which part you need specific help with.

Comment: This question would be better served if asked on Stack Overflow, as it is purely a software question.

Comment: Electrical or electronic engineering?

Comment: "*Gimme teh codez*" questions are a bit unpopular around here. Instead, show us what you have tried, and ask specific questions around technical stumbling blocks you are facing, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/FTP.

Note the FTP is above the socket connect layer to the Ethernet Shield's driver. So you it simply connecting the socket, just like the other client examples. Once connected then responding to the user/password prompt correctly, then issuing the FTP PUT command and finally sending or receiving the data.